# How do I set Expires: header when using send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-caching

I have a method in my controller which uses send_data like this:

```
def show
  expires_in 10.hours, :public => true
  send_data my_image_generator, :filename => "image.gif", :type => "image/gif"
end
```

Using expires_in results in headers being sent like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 25 Jun 2010 10:41:22 GMT
ETag: "885d75258e9306c46a5dbfe3de44e581"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
X-Runtime: 143
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.gif"
Content-Length: 1277
Cache-Control: max-age=36000, public
```

What I would like to do is add an header like `Expires: (some exact date)` to keep the user agent from revalidating. But I don't see how to make send_data set that header?

I guess I *could* set it explicitly in the `response.headers` hash, but surely there must be a wrapper for that (or something)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently there seems to be no way to pass expires to send_data - instead you must set it yourself in `response.headers` *and* take care of formatting the date appropriately:

```
response.headers["Expires"] = CGI.rfc1123_date(Time.now + period)
```

Note that the `max-age` directive in the `Cache-Control` header overrides the `Expires` header if both are present. See [RFC2616 Section 14.9.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) for more details.

Answer (score 29):

I came across this syntax and I like it :-)

```
response.headers["Expires"] = 1.year.from_now.httpdate
```

Comment: Do you put that in before or after the send_data?

Comment: Add before `send_data` ; once `send_data` is called, it's pointless to set the headers.

Comment: You need to `require "time"` in order to use this.

Comment: @NicolasGoy are you sure it's the case with rails? (I just tried this with Rails 4.2.0.beta4 and it worked without requiring `time`)

Comment: That's because rails requires it. But try in irb.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. This question is tagged with Rails =)

Comment: `from_now` (in the solution) requires Rails/ActiveSupport anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The code in your question should actually work on recent Rails:

```
`expires_in 10.hours, :public => true`
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly what the asker does in his original code?

Comment: Actually I found this does work on Rails 4.2, maybe Rails fixed a bug? Just be sure to avoid any manual headers being set in the same method. It has the additional benefit of letting you declare it as public.