# How to inspect and improve site performance ? ( Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, performance-testing

I read about improving site perforamance and tried to use some of them, but I'm not very competent in this, because of small amount of experience.

Firstly I need to saty, that I'm using thin server.

Here is what I done:

1. I made sprite image for icons ( static, hover, active )
2. Added compressing
3. Added compiling

I added this into mine development.rb file( previously installed required gems ):

```
config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.debug = false

config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

My very BAD result , when opening page at first time:

[image]
and after refresh it is a little better
[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is it better for performance to use images as backgrounds ( sprites ) ?
2. How to inspect site performance and look where I should work hareder ?
3. Am I'm usingcompiling/compressing wright ?
4. Should I put all my images in assets folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my answers for your questions:

1) You should use images as less as possible, because images reduce the page load time a lot. Should use CSS instead, just use image where we can't use CSS. Many pieces of images should be joined in a single one to reduce the number of request (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

2) There are a lot of tools that can help us monitor and improve the performance of our app. The two important things we can inspect and improve are the page load time (include static assets like images, css, js,...) and benchmark of the backend code (Ruby code).

I recommend these two tools to do the above measurement:

- YSlow (add-on for Firefox and Chrome): measure page load time with a
  lot of instruction of improvement.
- New Relic: tool to measure backend
  code: https://github.com/newrelic/rpm

Another tip, you should run Rails in development environment when optimizing code for performance. Because the app runs more slowly in dev mode than in production mode. If it runs fast in dev mode, it will run faster in production mode ;).

3) The way you are using assets compression is not wrong but strange :), because you are trying to compress assets in development mode (configure in development.rb) while we should do it in production mode instead (configure in production.rb).

4) It depends on your choice. But, yes, you should place all images in assets/images/ folder.

Comment: thanks. If I will use images as backgrounds it will be better or doesn't metter ? I just adding them in development.rb to test them) Or I should just choose environment when running server ?

Comment: Also I forgot to ask you about Bootstrap: I'm using it, but also downloaded js files, but I have bootstrap gem also. Can I improve something in this approach ?

Comment: Do you mean Twitter Bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap Rails gem?

Comment: i mean gem 'bootstrap-sass'. and I'm importing Bootstrap css using @import "bootstrap"; Is it ok ? Is it faster to use external(from Internet ) css,js files. Static are slower ?

Comment: I don't think 'bootstrap-sass' can improve performance. In fact, it's another way of writing CSS and JS. The Sass or SCSS script will be finally converted into CSS to make the browser understand. So it just makes your code cleaner, not in term of performance.

Comment: ok. thanks. I will make more research and maybe ask question again)

Comment: One more thing, if you using SASS, SCSS or Coffescript and access the page at the first time (in development mode), it will be rather slow! Because Rails must compile SASS, SCSS to native CSS and Coffescript to Javascript.

Comment: thanks. One more question : Yslow tells me to set expires header, but in assets pipeline guide I see option only for nginx and apache. Can I set them in thin server ?

Comment: You can set expires header in Rails. See more: http://upstre.am/blog/2011/10/http-caching-assets-in-rails-3-1/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117361/how-do-i-set-expires-header-when-using-send-data

Comment: Glad to know it can help you :D